# Exception thrown in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentity

Tags: c#

I'm trying to determine if the current user is a local windows user (not a domain user)

This is the code I'm using and in most cases it works however on some Windows computers that are not part of a domain it throws an exception

```
bool localUser = false;
WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
SecurityIdentifier sid = user.User;
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
using (Principal principal = Principal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.Sid, sid.ToString()))
{
    localUser = true;
}
```

This is the exception, stack trace

`````
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry'.
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMStoreCtx.GetAsPrincipal(Object storeObject, Object discriminant)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMStoreCtx.FindPrincipalByIdentRef(Type principalType, String urnScheme, String urnValue, DateTime referenceDate)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)````
`````

Comment: Oops, I missed that in the code example, fixed. The exception is getting thrown within the `FindByIdentity` call

Comment: Well, `System.DirectoryServices` is useful for accessing Active Directory Domain Services.  I'm not sure it can be expected to function when not connected to a domain system.

Comment: `Principal.FindByIdentity` takes a context, in this case `Machine` ie local machine ... and in most cases it works correctly. The issues I'm facing is sometimes I get an exception which seems to me a bug.

Comment: Hey, did you ever find what caused your bug? I'm having the same issue...